# Alternating Select based on Attributes

Tags: sql

I want to perform some dark magic using SQL, more specifically I want to alternate the result set between entries with certain attributes.

```
id | propertyX
1  | A
2  | A
3  | B
4  | B
5  | A
```

I want the resulting set of the select to alternate the entries between those with propertyX=A and propertyX=B which would yield the following (list of ids):

```
1,3,2,4,5
```

Can you perform such operations using SQL at all or do I have to do some post processing after selecting?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: what's the logic for ordering IDs ?

Comment: Are you trying to get five rows returned?  Or are you trying to concatenate these into a string?  The title suggests a single string, but the question suggests separate rows.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get a list of ids in this order, using the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select id
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by propertyX order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by seqnum, propertyX;
```

Actually, you don't even need the subquery, but I think it makes the logic clearer:

```
select id
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by propertyX order by id), propertyX;
```